# Office add-in: XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX due to access control checks

Tags: xmlhttprequest, office365, office-js, outlook-web-addins, javascript-api-for-office

I'm building an Outlook add-in with jQuery and the Office JS API. I have a local server going while developing, and I'm trying to submit a POST request to an endpoint on my site's main server. Every time I try to submit the request, I get the following three errors:

`Origin https://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myurl.com/my_endpoint due to access control checks`

`Failed to load resource: Origin https://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

What I've done so far:

Found this related thread: [HTTP fetch from within Outlook add-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628110/http-fetch-from-within-outlook-add-ins)

The only answer says to do three things:

1. Make the request with XMLHttpRequest. Yup, did that:

```
function submitForm(var1, var2) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = 'var1=' + encodeURIComponent(var1) + '&var2=' + encodeURIComponent(var2);
    http.open("POST", 'https://myurl.com/my_endpoint', true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://localhost:3000');
    http.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log("response:", http.responseText);
        console.log("status:", http.status);
    };
    http.send(params);
}
```

2. Add the service URL into the manifest's AppDomains list. Yup, did that, too. This is from my manifest.xml:

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://myurl.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://myurl.com/my_endpoint</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:3000</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

3. Use only services which are under SSL connection. Yup, the myurl.com server is only accessible via SSL.

I also found this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations) that recommends to solve this with cross-origin-resource-sharing (CORS), and points to this link: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-cors

So, I checked the server set-up for https://myurl.com and I am in fact allowing requests from any origin. UPDATE 1: as an example, here's what the output of a successful network request to https://myurl.com/my_endpoint looks like (notice the `Accept: */*` header):

```
Request URL: https://myurl.com/my_endpoint
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, public, max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 52
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: myurl.com
Origin: chrome-extension://focmnenmjhckllnenffcchbjdfpkbpie
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
var1: var1
var2: var2
```

Plus, another thing leading me to believe the problem isn't with https://myurl.com is: when I open my network tab in my debugger, I can see that my request never reaches https://myurl.com. I'm also not seeing the request pings in my https://myurl.com server logs. This is the output of my network request when I try to ping https://myurl.com from the Outlook add-in:

```
Summary
URL: https://myurl.com/my_endpoint
Status: —
Source: —

Request
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: https://localhost:3000
Accept: */*
Referer: https://localhost:3000/index.html?_host_Info=Outlook$Mac$16.02$en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko)

Response
No response headers

Request Data
MIME Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
var1: var1
var2: var2
```

Any recommendations for what else I need to change to enable making a POST request to myurl.com? Thanks in advance to the kind soul that helps me figure this out.

UPDATE 2: For what it's worth, I haven't done any configs to my node server beyond what came out-of-the box when I ran `npm install -g generator-office`. E.g. I haven't touched these two files:

`.babelrc`

```
{
    "presets": [
        "env"
    ]
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        polyfill: 'babel-polyfill',
        app: './src/index.js',
        'function-file': './function-file/function-file.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                use: 'file-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './index.html',
            chunks: ['polyfill', 'app']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './function-file/function-file.html',
            filename: 'function-file/function-file.html',
            chunks: ['function-file']
        })
    ]
};
```

Comment: It looks like you're using node.js. Can you please share how you configured the CORS to accept requests from any url?

Comment: I'm running a node server locally to host my add-in while developing. I really do think the problem is locally and not in the set up for the https://myurl.com server hosted on Azure with a Python back-end, but just for reference I've included the network output from a successful ping to https://myurl.com/my_endpoint in the question above

Answer (score 2):

> Failed to load resource: Origin https://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

The server responds to your `pre-flight` request (usually `OPTIONS`) and does not allow to get a response, that's because your origin `localhost:3000` is not allowed on server side.

You need to respond to `OPTIONS` on server with `204 status` code and a header like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'localhost';
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for taking the time to help. Please see above - I've already specified `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3000` in my request headers. Is there another place in my code that I should specify this in addition to what I've done already?

Comment: @tswift this header is set from server side not from client side.