# I am building an outlook add-in in node.js and it is not allowing me to call some other API

Tags: node.js, rest, outlook-web-addins

> I am a new developer in node.js(v10.15.1). I am trying to create an
>   outlook web Add-in in which I am making an API call to Spring
>   boot(v2.2) application and it is showing this error.
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxxxx' from origin
>   'https://localhost:3000' has been **blocked by CORS policy**: Response to
>   a preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Comment: I hope this helps [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628110/http-fetch-from-within-outlook-add-ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628110/http-fetch-from-within-outlook-add-ins)

Comment: @AshwaniGupta The problem is with localhost origin. Are you trying to connect to your own service?